# Batch script to enter a program fill the password field press enter and then press the button "Start"

Tags: batch-file, jscript

First time creating a .batch file.

I need to execute a program that already has the user field filled and insert the password and press enter. After some time it pops a window that need to be pressed a button called start. This is my attempt at enter the program. [image: 3rd button(Start]

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
 @echo off
    set "password=1234"
    start "" "C:\Programas\...exe"
    ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 >nul
    CScript //nologo //E:JScrpit "%~F0" "%password%{enter}"
    goto : EOF

    @end

    WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with `bash`, please remove the tag.

Comment: Só what is it? A .vbs?

Comment: I have no idea, but I know it is not `bash`.  Your wrote it, surely you know what it is?

Comment: @cdarke it is a batch file (considering the variables expansion using `%`).  I think the OP got it confused.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows thing to me.

Comment: Ohhh mb didnt notice sry, is a batch file

Comment: Also please edit the image link (delete spaces before the link), so it would not be part of the code and the image would become visible.

Comment: Luis Luis Maia Maia, I've replaced the `vbscript` tag you included because **`1.`** It isn't `vbscript`, it is `jscript` and **`2.`** You should have already known, you told `CScript` what it was on line `4`, _(despite your typo)_.